# Use json file only client side in meteor

Tags: json, meteor

I have a json file with information scrapped dayly from the web and as it's just a small array I decided to put it in a file in the public folder and read it client side. The array will be used as the options for a select tag. 
I would like to read it only client side without pinging the server. How can I read the file in a template helper?

As I'm new to web development the file client side solution was the one I thought was best. If you believe there's a better way please state it and explain why is better. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the http package to make a httprequest to the 'public' folder.

```
HTTP.get("yourweb/yourfile.json",{},function(error,result){
//do something with result
});
```

https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html

Comment: The solo purpose of this is to return the result but as the function is asynchronous I can't. How can I return the result from the helper?

Comment: I would use a reactive variable for that. At template creation you initialize the reactive var and call HTTP get. In the HTTP get callback you set the reactive var value to the result (while parsing JSON). In the helper you get the value from the reactive var.